# Routing is not working for web api with realtions

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, coreclr

I am creating web api using asp.net core. The api end point is logically mapped to resource's relations based on [guidelines here](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#requirements)
So my API looks like

```
      http://tax.mydomain.com/api/v1/clients/1/batches/12/start
```

Where `Client` is parent of `Batch`,  `1` is clientid and `12` is batchid, and `Start` is POST action method.

Here is the corresponding controller

```
public class TaxController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("clients/{clientid}/batches/{batchid}/start")]
    public void Start([FromRoute]string clientId, [FromRoute]string batchId, 
                      [FromBody]IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

since `api/v1` is common to all controllers i configured that in startup's `Configure` method. Also i want `Home` as default controller.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
        routes.MapRoute("default","api/v1/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });
    }
```

However client is getting not found error for api `http://tax.mydomain.com/api/v1/clients/1/batches/12/start`

Comment: Turn `[Route("clients/{clientid}/batches/{batchid}/start")]` into `[Route("api/v1/clients/{clientid}/batches/{batchid}/start")]`

Answer (score 1):

> Any controller methods that do not have a route attribute use convention-based routing.

When you use `[Route]` attribute, you define attribute routing and so conventional routing is not used for that action/controller. Therefore, your controller is accessible by

```
http://tax.mydomain.com/clients/1/batches/12/start
```

As an option, you can use the fact, that attribute routes can be combined with inheritance. Set a `Route` attribute on the entire controller and this will work as route prefix (the same behavior as `[RoutePrefix]` attribute in WebApi):

```
[Route("api/v1")]
public class TaxController : Controller
{

}
```

More general example from [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) documentation:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller { ... }

public class ProductsController : MyBaseController
{
   [HttpGet] // Matches '/api/Products'
   public IActionResult List() { ... }

   [HttpPost("{id}")] // Matches '/api/Products/{id}'
   public IActionResult Edit(int id) { ... }
}
```

Comment: does route prefix has to set at controller level? can we set it in startup.cs? if yes how?

Comment: @LP13 only on a controller level. Attribute routing is about specific actions in the specific controller. Otherwise, you are turning back to convention-based routing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your setup

1. You call `http://tax.mydomain.com/clients/1/batches/12/start` but you don't have specified the controller name within it. This route looks for a controller named `ClientsController`. So the correct url would have to be `http://tax.mydomain.com/tax/clients/1/batches/12/start` instead
2. You seem to be using default MVC/Viewbased route, but your url suggest you use WebAPI.

   When you use WebAPI to create a Rest service, you don't have any actions. Instead, actions map to the Http Verbs (GET (Read), PUT (update/replace), POST (insert), DELETE).

   So for REST Services your default route should look like this instead:  `api/v1/{controller=Home}/{id?}`

Comment: well i dont want `tax` again in the url since its already part of subdomain. i changed the controller name to `clients` but that didnt help either

Comment: If you are creating a rest service (WebAPI), you don't have to define actions, because the http verbs define them. You'll have to remove the action from your default route like in 2. section and then call your controller "ClientsController" or change the calling url to `http://tax.mydomain.com/tax/1/batches/12/start`